# How to draw the outline of multiple US states in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to draw the outline of multiple US states in R using longitude and latitude points. Now I can only draw the outline of each states, so I want to know the way to draw the outline of multiple US states(only the outer line).

```
library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)    
library(broom)
library(stringr)
library(modelr)
library(forcats)
library(ggmap)


states <- map_data("state")# %>% as_tibble()
counties <- map_data("county")
il_df <- filter(fifty_states, id == "illinois")
midwest <- subset(fifty_states, id %in% c("illinois", "indiana", "iowa",
                                    "kansas", "michigan", "minnesota",
                                    "missouri", "nebraska", "north dakota",
                                    "ohio", "south dakota", "wisconsin"))


il_mid <- ggplot(data = midwest, mapping = aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) + 
  coord_fixed(1.3) + 
  geom_polygon(color = "black", fill = "gray")
il_mid
```

[image]

I want to know how to draw the pink line in below image.

[image]

Comment: What is the question? You have plotted multiple states as shown.

Comment: @CalumYou I want to draw only one outline of multiple states, not the outlines of each states

Comment: Perhaps `rgeos::gUnion` will work here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an approach using the `sf` package and the convenient `geom_sf` in the development version of `ggplot2`. I get the map data from the nice `fiftystater` package that provides Alaska and Hawaii as insets, but it requires conversion to `sf` format. I use an answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49526198/convert-a-fortified-data-frame-back-to-sf-object/49539006#49539006) to do this.

Then the rest is simple, we just `filter` to the right states, union them together with `summarise.sf`, and then use `geom_sf` to plot the result.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.6.1, GDAL 2.2.3, proj.4 4.9.3
library(fiftystater)

sf_fifty <- sf::st_as_sf(fifty_states, coords = c("long", "lat")) %>% 
  group_by(id, piece) %>% 
  summarize(do_union = FALSE) %>%
  st_cast("POLYGON") %>% 
  ungroup()

midwest <- sf_fifty %>%
  filter(
    id %in% c(
      "illinois", "indiana", "iowa",
      "kansas", "michigan", "minnesota",
      "missouri", "nebraska", "north dakota",
      "ohio", "south dakota", "wisconsin"
    )
  ) %>%
  summarise(id = "midwest")

ggplot() +
  theme_minimal() +
  geom_sf(data = sf_fifty) +
  geom_sf(data = midwest, col = "hotpink", alpha = 0, size = 2)
```

[image]

Created on 2018-05-24 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick & dirty method that works for your example, assuming you want to outline all outer edges:

```
ggplot(data = midwest, mapping = aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) + 
  coord_fixed(1.3) + 
  geom_polygon(color = "hotpink", size = 5) + # or some other arbitrarily large number
  geom_polygon(color = "black", fill = "gray")
```

The additional `geom_polygon` layer has pink outline for every polygon, but only the edges not covered by the original layer are visible.

[image: plot]

Note that this won't work for more complicated cases (e.g. you wish to plot all US states, but show outline for Northeast / Midwest / South / West states). In that case, you'll probably need to merge the data frame to an appropriate spatial object and merge the underlying polygons, e.g. using `rgeos::gUnion` as per @r2evans' suggestion.

Comment: Thank you! Actually I want to plot all US states but show outline for some multiple states with outlines, So I may need to use `rgeos::gUnion`.